# Prove that $ \operatorname {dom} G \setminus \operatorname {dom} H \subseteq \operatorname {dom} ( G \setminus H ) $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

im trying to learn some basics from set theory, and I got stuck in this proof.

> Prove that
> $$ \operatorname {dom} G \setminus \operatorname {dom} H \subseteq \operatorname {dom} ( G \setminus H ) \text . $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$Suppose that $x\in\dom G\setminus\dom H$. Then $x\in\dom G$, so there is some $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in G$. And $x\notin\dom H$, so there is no $z$ such that $\langle x,z\rangle\in H$. In particular, $\langle x,y\rangle\notin H$, so $\langle x,y\rangle\in G\setminus H$. One more small step, which I’ll leave to you, and you’re done.